# Use of unassigned local variable 'x'

Tags: c#, variables

This code:

```
int a;
if(a==1){ do something}
```

or

```
Image img;
   if(img!=null){do something}
```

These codes generates the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'variable-name'

I know what exactly this error says and how to resolve it. but what I wonder is that

1. Shouldn't a variable that is declared and not assigned a value, have a value? like `null` for the `Image`

2.Why wouldn't it allow to even compare the variable? it can simply say that it doesn't match.

Comment: The use of an uninitialized variable is usually a bug.  It probably stems from C/C++ when an uninitiazlized variable could have random data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Shouldn't a variable that is declared and not assigned a value, have a value? like null for the `Image'

No. That's just not the way the language is defined. Local variables do not have default values in C# (or most other languages, but by no means all).

> 2.Why wouldn't it allow to even compare the variable? it can simply say that it doesn't match.

Because you're trying to read the value of a variable that you've never assigned a value to, which is a bug (in C#) by definition. Thus, it's calling your attention to that bug.

Comment: "or most other languages" --- most, or least?

Comment: @zerkms: Most high-level languages that I'm familiar with do not assign default values to local variables -- C, Java, C#, ... The exception in my everyday experience is JavaScript, which defaults them to `undefined`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/buBn58 ?

Comment: @zerkms: Shows how rusty my C++ is (it's been more than 20 years).

Comment: C++ _lets_ you use unassigned local variables, but not all compilers _initialize_ them.  There just happened to be zeros in the memory location that the compiler allocated for the variable.

Comment: Yep, I see now. I confused it with something else.